# Styled-components and theming with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, next.js

I try to create a Theme for all of my components in the app, I tried to but failed with **/pages/_app.js:**

```
import App, { Container } from "next/app"; // eslint-disable-line
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider } from "styled-components";

export default class MyApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {};

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
    }

    return { pageProps };
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
    return (
      <Container>
        <ThemeProvider theme={{ color: 'blue' }}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

But in my components `theme` prop is always an empty Object:

```
const A = styled.a`
  color: ${props => {
    console.log(props);
    return "blue";
  }};
`;
```

Comment: did you manage to solve it? having the same issue.

Comment: @JuHwon it should work with nextjs 6 and above. See https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/4170

Comment: @JuHwon I just updated an example in NextJS repo, take a look https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components. There's also link to codesanbox there where you can run it.

Comment: tanks for your response. it seems that i had some kind of version conflict. i had issues with the next version ^8.1.0, though when i used 8.0.6 it worked again. I see you are working with the latest next, so this should be specific to my setup. thx.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
const A = styled.a`
  color: ${props => props.theme.color};
`;
```